# How do I determine how fast I can switch a load configured to high and low side switching?

Tags: mosfet, cmos

I would like to switch a load on both high and low side. I would like to know the capabilities of the MOSFET switch IC I have chosen. Specifically, what is the highest frequency I can switch them? For my high side IC is the [BTS7040](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS7040-2EPA-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625e763904015e9412cf6e2dbb) and the low side is the [BM2LC105](https://d1d2qsbl8m0m72.cloudfront.net/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/ipd/bxxlc105fj-c-e.pdf).

Since both of the IC use NMOS as a switch the circuit would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXPnBCm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I could not find an obvious specification in the data sheet on how fast I can switch these ICs Is there anyway to extrapolate this information?

Comment: I recommend reviewing Section 7.4 in the Infineon datasheet and Page 8 for Rohm datasheet.

Comment: You must use PWM to create a boost bias voltage for hi side Vgs and MUST define load complex impedance.

Comment: @KingDuken duken thank you for pointing that out, please correct me if im wrong the worst maximum times between the two ic is 110us (9090Hz) meaning my switching should be slower than that value. Is it safe to use a maximum of 9000Hz or it should be way below that value

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes i am planning to use PWM for the fast switching but.... I am not sure what you mean by "to create boost bias voltage for hi side Vgs". The PWM i plan to use is only 50% duty cycle, How do i calculate the appropriate duty cycle if 50% wont cut it?

Comment: Any duty cycle works on negative edge clamp boost but you are doing this all backwards . DEFINE DA SPECS for all impedances THEN Choose parts and frequency IMax must be around 10x actual surge currents

Comment: @adamaero I have rolled back your edits because they were pretty useless and screwed with the intent of the original question. If you are embarking on a course of making amendments to questions I insist you double or triple check your modifications.

Comment: Ah, no thanks. Rather, you should have edited it further. The grammar is horrid.